# Extract the last word between | |

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have the following dataset

```
> head(names$SAMPLE_ID)
[1] "Bacteria|Proteobacteria|Gammaproteobacteria|Pseudomonadales|Moraxellaceae|Acinetobacter|"
[2] "Bacteria|Firmicutes|Bacilli|Bacillales|Bacillaceae|Bacillus|"                            
[3] "Bacteria|Proteobacteria|Gammaproteobacteria|Pasteurellales|Pasteurellaceae|Haemophilus|" 
[4] "Bacteria|Firmicutes|Bacilli|Lactobacillales|Streptococcaceae|Streptococcus|"             
[5] "Bacteria|Firmicutes|Bacilli|Lactobacillales|Streptococcaceae|Streptococcus|"             
[6] "Bacteria|Firmicutes|Bacilli|Lactobacillales|Streptococcaceae|Streptococcus|"
```

I want to extract the last word between `||` as a new variable i.e.

```
Acinetobacter
Bacillus
Haemophilus
```

I have tried using

```
library(stringr)
names$sample2 <-   str_match(names$SAMPLE_ID, "|.*?|")
```

Comment: The easy route: `vapply(strsplit(names$SAMPLE_ID, "|", fixed = TRUE), tail, "", 1)`

Comment: Or of you don't like typing (or efficiency) then `sapply(strsplit(x, "\\|"), tail, 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last_regex(v1, '\\w+')
#[1] "Acinetobacter"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "Bacteria|Proteobacteria|Gammaproteobacteria|Pseudomonadales|Moraxellaceae|Acinetobacter|"
```

Comment: seems that `stringi` package is better than `stringr` in some aspects.

Answer (score 5):

Using just base R:

```
myvar <- gsub("^..*\\|(\\w+)\\|$", "\\1", names$SAMPLE_ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
^.*\\|\\K.*?(?=\\|)
```

Use `\K` to remove rest from the final matche.See demo.Also use `perl=T`

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/45

```
x <- c("Bacteria|Firmicutes|Bacilli|Lactobacillales|Streptococcaceae|Streptococcus|",
       "Bacteria|Firmicutes|Bacilli|Lactobacillales|Streptococcaceae|Streptococcus|" )

unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr('^.*\\|\\K.*?(?=\\|)', x, perl = TRUE)))
# [1] "Streptococcus" "Streptococcus"
```

Answer (score 3):

The ending is all you need `[^|]+(?=\|$)`

Per @RichardScriven :

`Which in R would be regmatches(x, regexpr("[^|]+(?=\\|$)", x, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use package "stringr" as well in this case. Here is the code:

`v<- "Bacteria|
Proteobacteria|Gammaproteobacteria|Pseudomonadales|Moraxellaceae|Acinetobacter|"`

`v1<- str_replace_all(v, "\\|", " ")`

`word(v1,-2)`

Here I used v as the string. The basic theory is to replace all the `|` with spaces, and then get the last word in the string by using function `word()`.